# How to add filter inside my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble using the Angular filter in my app.

I have something like

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $filter){
   myService.get('api/v1/products/?id=1').success(function(data) {
       $scope.products = data;    
       $filter('testFilter', function() {
           return function(products, item) {             
               //codes...
           }
       })   
   })
}
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | testFilter:5 "> {{product.title}} </div>
```

However, I am getting `testFilterProvider` unknown error. Can someone help me out on this one? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To create a filter, you need to call `filter()` on the module...

```
app.filter('testFilter', function() {
    return function(products, item) {             
         //codes...
    };
});
```

And if you want use that filter in your controller, you can call the `$filter` service to retrieve it...

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $filter){
   myService.get('api/v1/products/?id=1').success(function(data) {
       $scope.products = data;    
       var filteredProducts = $filter('testFilter')($scope.products, 5);
   });
}
```

Comment: so I have create filter() on the module whether I need the filter inside the controller or not? +1

Comment: I believe so. You can also just put the function on the scope: `$scope.testFilter = function(products, item) { ... }` and use it in a less elegant way... `ng-repeat="product in testFilter(products, 5) "`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to call out filter on module level and inside the controller at the same time. I was assuming I only need to do your second portion of the codes and be done with it. It's just not working

Comment: Filters are meant to be reusable components, so I guess that's why they exist at the module level. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do that's not working?